Can I setup a sink drain to this in my basement?
We are finishing the basement and would like to put a sink in the basement. How do I tell if I can drain to this? It's right below in main water line coming into the house.

That should be a cleanout tap for the main drain.  I don't know of any code that prevents you from adding a wye and using it to drain a sink but still retain a clean out.  Maybe the plumbing pros can give a definitive answer.

There's no definitive way to tell what pipes buried in cement are,  but that's probably a cleanout for your main drain out to the street.
Test that theory: While nobody is using any water, open it.  If you can see the horizontal pipe below it, great.  If not, buy a cheap borescope and stick it in until it joins the main drain.   Then open a tap.  You should soon see that tap's water flowing past.  If you want to be SUPER sure you can fill the sink slightly, add some food coloring, or rice crispies, or whatever, and you should see that flow past.
If that succeeds, you can extend that pipe to provide a connection for your new sink and a new cleanout.  Your new sink will need a vent.   If you can find a path to one up in the basement ceiling that would be good, otherwise you can use a mechanical one.
Notes

If you do find a vent pipe in the ceiling, it will most likely be a "wet vent" (a drain pipe for upstairs fixtures) and you should have a trusted knowledgeable plumber install it. There are a lot of ways to get it wrong.
if your main line is somewhat backed up and there has been a lot of water use in your house in the last few minutes/hours, opening that cap could produce a very unpleasant mess.
If you are decorating the basement floor AND opening up the cleanout, it would be a good investment to actually clean out the main drain proactively.


In any event the OP needs reasonable access to the clean out, which does not seem to be the case here based on the picture.

@JonCuster good point, and IDK, it looks like there will be an access door for the meter and the cleanout can be accessed that way.

Was just about to say the same.  The opening looks like for a door of some type(cabinet?)

That water meter and main shutoff will need to retain access anyway, and that access can double for the sanitary plumbing.

I have it framed out to put up some small access cover (cabinet door or something).
